# Cannot install Sharepoint 2013 or 2010 on Server 2012 box

Tags: sharepoint

When I try to install SharePoint 2010 Foundation on a Windows Server 2012 machine with SQL Server 2012 already installed I get the message "The installation of this package failed" after running installer file as Administrator. The log files in %user%\Appdata\local\temp\2 do not give any clues as to what has gone wrong. If I download Sharepoint Foundation 2013 and run that as Administrator I get the same error.

IE on the Server 2012 machine has protected mode turned off and the server has IIS and AppServer features enabled

Answer (score 0):

I had other S/W as well as Server2012 on the target box - SQL Server, Classic Shell, MS Office so something there was preventing SP install from running. Reinstalling Server2012 removed problem.